# What's a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What exactly is a differential equation? Pray, is $$\frac{dx}{dt}= x(x(t))$$ not a DE?

Because Arnold thinks not. In a note on page 11 of his *Ordinary Differential Equations,* he says, 'Differential equations are sometimes said to be equations containing unknown functions and their derivatives. This is false...'

And this is -- I remember -- exactly what we were told during our undergraduate ODE classes; I also have found this in many other places -- books, online, etc. So Arnold's comment is strange and seems like nonsense.

Who has an idea what he means, or why he's saying this?

Comment: If you take the time to browse a bit the site you will notice **immediately** that no one writes titles all in caps. Don't do it, please.

Comment: Perhaps a differential equation is just what it sounds like: an equation in terms of differentials.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \dfrac{dx}{dt} = x(x(t))$$ is not a differential equation, it is a functional differential equation.  A differential equation is an equation containing an unknown function and its derivatives, all **evaluated at the same  independent variable(s)**.  An equation containing $x'(t)$ and $x(\text{something else})$ is not a differential equation.